# In Google Slides, is there a workaround for downloading when PDF goes wrong?

Tags: google-slides

A nightmare scenario... Presentation completed, I download my slides as PDF ready for presentation via USB. Several of the images fail to appear in the PDF. This holds true for different PDF readers on multiple devices. Similarly, the print preview from Google Slides does not show said images.

In my case, the images in question were from Draw.io. But a quick search reveals that others have had [similar problems](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/RHzvFYwjuZQ). The images do appear in the PowerPoint version, but as expected this version requires heavy reformatting before it can be presented.

So, if I were to find myself in a similar situation again, is there another way to download a stable (WYSIWYG) version of a Google Slides presentation aside from `download as>PDF'?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Download a file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2423534?hl=en) the available formats to download presentations are PDF, PPTX and TXT, but the "Download as" menu option, shows other formats like JPG, PNG and SVG. The "problem" with this solution is that this options exports only one slide at a time.

[image]